# Query polygons using ogrinfo but not generate a new layer

Tags: geometry, ogr, intersect

I want to list the polygons in my layer A that intersects other polygon B, using ogr. 
The desired result is similar to "Select by location" tool in QGIS or ArcGIS Desktop, where I expect an index of table A, and **NOT** a new layer with the intersected geometry.

I'ld like to get the result like: 1, 4, 6 ... where the numbers represent the rows of A where B intersects, or the table A [ "Rows where A intersects B", ], and store in a file if possible.

Additionally I'll prefer to replace the B layer for a WKT string like 
`Polygon ((12 13, 11 12, ...))`, just to avoid ask a new question.

Currently I'm using this expression using .vrt file:

```
ogrinfo vrt.vrt -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) AS geometry FROM a a, b b" -geom=SUMMARY
```

And the results:

```
Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 36
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["Transverse_Mercator",
    GEOGCS["GCS_GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",4.596200417],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-74.07750791700001],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1000000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",1000000],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Geometry Column = geometry
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  MULTIPOLYGON : 3 geometries:
POLYGON : 168 points
POLYGON : 22972 points
POLYGON : 1990 points

OGRFeature(SELECT):1

OGRFeature(SELECT):2
....
OGRFeature(SELECT):17
  MULTIPOLYGON : 3 geometries:
POLYGON : 1251 points
POLYGON : 544 points
POLYGON : 15937 points
```

Comment: In the heading you refer to `ogrinfo` but in the question you use `ogr2ogr`. Have you tried the command with `ogrinfo` already?

Comment: Yes. I'll made the update in my question. Thanks

Comment: Pay attention to difference between ST_Intersects and ST_Intersection..

Comment: Yes!!! Works better using ```ogrinfo vrt.vrt -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) AS geometry FROM a a, b b" -geom=SUMMARY -fields=YES -nomd -noextent```. Any idea about using a ```Polgon() ``` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to:

1. Replace the second geometry by using: `ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(( # #, # #,  ... ))'`
2. Select the required columns: `column1, column2, column3`
3. Use the SQL function `ST_Intersects`

```
ogrinfo myTargetLayer.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM myTargetLayer WHERE ST_Intersects(GEOMETRY, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(( # #, # #,  ... ))')"
```